# How to hide/ disable notices or warning in magento

Tags: magento-1.8, file-permissions

How to hide/ disable notices or warning in magento 1.8 ?

Comment: What you mean `hide/ disable notices`. admin notification?

Comment: Actually i need to put folder permission on media 0555 this is our requirement .doing so there is an message like  folder dont writeable folder dont writeable comes.how to get rid from this.for this i want to hide notices

Comment: Any suggession will be appreciated.also tell me what permission allowed by Magento for var folder

Answer (score 1):

Please add below line code in your index.php file.

```
  error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_DEPRECATED);
```